# CSS load after redirect to https fails on WP7 browser

Tags: css, redirect, https

I have a test web page in Azure cloud where I have login page in https. My problem is that if I get to the login page via redirect, neither the CSS or images get loaded in WP7 default browser - IE. Certificate is a self signed one - so I get the warning from browser before getting to the actual page.

The strange thing is that if I just click on refresh button after the initial loading - CSS and images gets loaded OK. Also, if I go to the https login page directly without going through redirect - everything works OK again.

Server side is done with MVC3 and https redirect is done by adding [RequireHttps] attribute before the controller.

Fiddler logs do not show anything that would help me. In the redirect case I can see that after the html page has been loaded there is handshaking for getting the https tunnel up, but no requests for css or images. When I click refresh, Fiddler log seems to start the same way, but this time also CSS and image is loaded.

I have done quite a bit googling on this and none of the answers that I have found seem to help. CSS and image are loaded with relative links, so that should not be the issue. Directory access rights should be OK as well, because it works without redirect. It also works OK in Desktop IE and other mobile browsers that I have tried on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.